# How to keep precision of float->String conversion on PostgreSQL JDBC connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have a PostgreSQL function, which accepts JSON, performs some processing, and returns JSON. Something strange is happening when calling stored procedure from Java appication - float->string convertion is incorrect.

Processing is mostly filtering of data and returning restructured and reorganized result. For simplicity let's assume input is map `[name->float]` and output is `[float]`.

The problem is that during intermediate data storage of values into native PostgreSQL data type float values lose precision/accuracy/formatting.

Here is the code to reproduce

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_dummy()
    RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    v_float float[];
    v_json jsonb;
    v_str varchar;
BEGIN
    v_float[0] = 4.1;
    raise notice 'v_float = %', v_float[0];
    raise notice 'jsonb float -> %', ('{"v": 4.1}'::jsonb)->'v';
    raise notice 'jsonb float ->> %', ('{"v": 4.1}'::jsonb)->>'v';

    v_float[0] = ('{"v": 4.1}'::jsonb)->>'v';
    raise notice 'jsonb float ->>::float %', v_float[0];

    v_json = array_to_json(v_float);
    raise notice 'jsonb: %', v_json;

    v_str = concat('jsonb as string: ', v_json::varchar);
    raise notice '%', v_str;
END $$
```

When executing

```
select do_dummy();
```

... via pgAdmin, output is following and is as expected:

```
NOTICE:  v_float = 4.1
NOTICE:  jsonb float -> 4.1
NOTICE:  jsonb float ->> 4.1
NOTICE:  jsonb float ->>::float 4.1
NOTICE:  jsonb: [4.1]
NOTICE:  jsonb as string: [4.1]
```

When executing same from Java application, result is following

```
NOTICE: v_float = 4.0999999999999996
NOTICE: jsonb float -> 4.1
NOTICE: jsonb float ->> 4.1
NOTICE: jsonb float ->>::float 4.0999999999999996
NOTICE: jsonb: [4.0999999999999996]
NOTICE: jsonb as string: [4.0999999999999996]
```

Since no data is transferred to/from server in function call - problem occurs completely server-side, but something in JDBC driver is triggering the problem.

What can be wrong with JDBC connection in this regard?

*I'm using jdbc driver v9.4.1207 (the latest one at the moment)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver initializes [`extra_float_digits`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS).

If you run

```
set extra_float_digits = 0;
```

before calling your function, you get the same output via JDBC

Comment: Yes, running `show extra_float_digits` in pgAdmin returns `0`. Now the question is what is the optimal way to deal with `extra_float_digits`. I believe i need `extra_float_digits=0` for all my staff but executing `set extra_float_digits = 0;` before each SQL function call seems to be over complicated overhead. Is there some 'global' way to configure that option for driver or Java process or database? BTW, i.m. using c3p0 (http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) for connection pooling. I've tried setting `extra_float_digits` with no result.

Comment: @XtraCoder: no idea, you should ask that on the Postgres JDBC mailing list. But I find your code to return real data as part of a `notice` message to be questionable to begin with. If you return those number as a proper result set, you don't have to convert them to a String and can process them as numbers directly in Java (you also might want to rethink the use of a `float` anyway due to the fact that it is only an approximate data type)

Comment: Out of your quick answer I suspected you also known further way :) - ok, will dig JDBC further on my own. Anywhay, thanks for the starting point. ... Regarding `String` vs. `float` in general - sample just tries to iterate some possible combinations and their affect on result. I'm mostly care about storing numeric value in 'rather natural' JSON after manipulation.